# ShareThis Accessability Issue - How to Add Keyboard Support

Tags: accessibility

I'm working on an existing project and make some fixes for accessibility support. One of the items from my accessibility list refers to the ShareThis social buttons. For some reason it doesn't support navigation from keyboard. I've added `"tabindex=0"` attribute to all social icons `<span>` elements. So now I can navigate, but I can't activate it by clicking "Enter". Do I really need to write my own JS functions for all this buttons? Maybe there is accessability solution that somebody wrote before for ShareThis?

Answer (score 1):

The tabindex attribute you added will make the spans focusable by keyboard, but doesn't provide any support for Enter events. You will need to add listeners for Enter in JavaScript. Alternatively you could switch the spans to links or buttons - these have native keyboard support so won't need the additional JavaScript.